# Android app built with React Native and Expo still asking for app permissions

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I built an Android app using React Native and building the apk file using expo `expo build:android`. However, when I run the app on an emulator, even after removing all permissions from AndroidManifest.xml, the app still asks for Physical Activity permissions:

android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="<package.name>">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>

<!-- OPTIONAL PERMISSIONS, REMOVE WHATEVER YOU DO NOT NEED -->

<!-- These require runtime permissions on M -->
<!-- END OPTIONAL PERMISSIONS -->

<application
  android:name=".MainApplication"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
  android:allowBackup="false"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

  <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_UPDATE_URL" android:value="YOUR-APP-URL-HERE" />
  <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_SDK_VERSION" android:value="YOUR-APP-SDK-VERSION-HERE" />

  <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>
  <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
</application>
```

**Permissions Screenshot**

[image]

I have tried adding the `tools:node="remove"` tag rather than removing the uses-permissions lines but this had no effect.

My app requires no permissions and this issue is preventing me from uploading to the Play Store. I read in other posts that a library I am using might be requesting permissions but I do not believe any of the npm libraries I am using would require any such permissions:

package.json

```
{
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "av": "^0.4.9",
    "expo": "~37.0.3",
    "expo-av": "^8.1.0",
    "expo-updates": "~0.1.0",
    "react": "~16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "~16.9.0",
    "react-native": "~0.61.5",
    "react-native-elements": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.6.0",
    "react-native-modal": "^11.5.6",
    "react-native-popup-dialog": "^0.18.3",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.7.0",
    "react-native-responsive-fontsize": "^0.4.3",
    "react-native-responsive-screen": "^1.4.1",
    "react-native-screens": "~2.2.0",
    "react-native-unimodules": "~0.9.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.11.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "~7.9.0",
    "babel-jest": "~25.2.6",
    "jest": "~25.2.6",
    "react-test-renderer": "~16.9.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

So after some further digging, https://docs.expo.io/workflow/configuration/?redirected, what fixed this issue was adding `android.permissions = []` to my app.json:

```
 "android": {
 "package": "<package name>",
 "versionCode": 1,
 "permissions": []}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. How we update the same on the app download page on Playstore?